# Rails4 Minitest | using a shared reusable object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, minitest

I am getting the following error when I run rake test with minitest:

```
$ rake test
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Run options: --seed 55196

# Running:

.EE

Finished in 0.950979s, 3.1546 runs/s, 1.0515 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CategoryTest#test_invalid_without_name:
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/category_test.rb:14:in `test_invalid_without_name'


  2) Error:
CategoryTest#test_invalid_without_long_name:
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/category_test.rb:19:in `test_invalid_without_long_name'

3 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

category_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def category
    @category = Category.new(name:'Homey')
  end

  def test_valid
    assert category.valid?
  end

  def test_invalid_without_name
    @category.name = nil
    refute @category.valid?
  end

  def test_invalid_without_long_name
    @category.name = "A"
    refute @category.valid?
  end

end
```

In my models I have the category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

It seems that I have a nil class even though I am instantiating it in my category method. Any idea what is happening. I am just getting started using Minitest so not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
def category
  @category ||= Category.new(name:'Homey')
end
```

Then only use `category` not `@category`

Using a getter this way will set the instance var if it didnt exist before or retrieve the existing value

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to approach this, but the most straightforward would be to replace the `category` method with:

`def setup
  @category = Category.new(name:'Homey')
end`